# Tkinter scrollbar trough click

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbars

Is there a bug in the natural scrollbar trough click event handler, is something wrong with the way I set it up, or something else? I ask because it doesn't always work (when it doesn't work, it either does nothing or else moves to the wrong position). The scrollbars otherwise work fine. Sometimes the trough clicks do work, but a lot of the time they don't. (More than one or two clicks is often needed to discover the problem.)

```
hbar=Scrollbar(newTabFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL, bg=self.d["hbgcolor"], troughcolor=self.d["htcolor"]);
vbar=Scrollbar(newTabFrame, orient=VERTICAL, bg=self.d["vbgcolor"], troughcolor=self.d["vtcolor"]);
scroll=Text(self, newTabFrame, font=self.d["font"], undo=True, tabs=("0.4c"), wrap=self.d["wrap"], xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set, bg=self.d["bgcolor"], fg=self.d["fgcolor"], insertbackground=self.d["insertcolor"]);

vbar.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, sticky=N+S);
vbar.config(command=scroll.yview);
hbar.grid(sticky=E+W);
hbar.config(command=scroll.xview);
```

Once again, it's only when I click on the troughs where I experience a problem. All the other scrollbar functionality (which is most of it) works fine. For those who don't know, a scrollbar trough is the long part of the scrollbar that does not move.

My scrollbars are attached to Text widgets inside Frames that are inside of `ttk.Notebook` widget tabs.

Comment: What platform is this on, and are you using tkinter scrollbars or ttk scrollbars?

Comment: I'm using Linux (Xubuntu 14.04, 32-bit). I'm using the ttk Scrollbar class, come to think of it.

Comment: I just tested the regular Scrollbar class, and it does the same thing with it. It might be an issue caused by a bug in my larger code, but it wouldn't have to do with my scrollbars directly, if so.

Comment: It's not my bindings I had on my Notebook widget interfering, I just discovered.

Comment: There are no known problems related to clicking in the trough of a scrollbar. Have you tried reproducing the problem with the smallest possible program? My guess is you have some errant binding somewhere causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I don't know of any bindings that would be causing the problem. I'll have to try your suggestion and post the results. My current guess is it's the grid layout manager, how I have it set up, maybe, since I don't understand how I'm getting the result I am with the arguments I'm using. I'll have to see if it does the same thing without arguments, or with pack, and try other things than Xubuntu, too.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yep! You were totally right. I did have a binding to Button-1. The problem was in my code that updates the statusbar. It calls Text.see(INSERT), which, of course, interferes with the scrollbar trough clicks, seeing as moving with the trough doesn't move the insert.

Comment: Using `Event.num` to determine if it's a mouse click or the keyboard so as to disable `Text.see()` with the mouse seems to work. I need it to call `Text.see()` for the keyboard, but not particularly for the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, no, there is no known bug in the scrollbar code. This code has been in use for more than a decade without anyone reporting issues with the trough. That doesn't mean a bug isn't possible, but it is highly unlikely. There also doesn't appear to be any problems with how you defined the scrollbar or how you attached it to the text widget. .

Based on comments to the original question, it sounds like you have some bindings in your app that may be interfering with the default behavior of the scrollbar.